# How do you fix Javac in MacOsx High Sierra

Tags: java, macos, javac

Pretty much says it all:

```
% javac
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java//bin/javac" (-1)
% which javac
/usr/bin/javac
% file /usr/bin/javac
/usr/bin/javac: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [i386:Mach-O executable i386]
/usr/bin/javac (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/javac (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386
%
```

How do I put Humpty Dumpty back together after installing the upgrade to OS-X?  (Latest) . (Actually, no clue it worked before this either)

Clearly, it is 'there', and the 'man' page is there too (not that 90% of the users know what that even is anymore.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that the JAVA_HOME was set wrong.  Unsetting this made it run.